# How to set DockPanel.Dock value in a Setter?

Tags: c#, wpf

When creating a *style* or *trigger* e.g. for a TextBlock in XAML you can easily do:

```
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="64" />
```

How to do the same with `'DockPanel.Dock'`, which is an attached property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess

```
<Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ControlName" Value="Right"/>
```